# Why does the recycle bin icon on the desktop appear full even though the recycle bin is empty?

Tags: windows-xp, recycle-bin

On Windows XP, I've noticed that sometimes the recycle bin icon on my desktop appears full even when there are no files in it.  If I right click on the recycle bin or open it and go to the file menu, the "Empty Recycle Bin" menu item is disabled.

What causes this state, and how can I get the icon to show that the bin is empty?

Comment: What icon size do you have your desktop set to? Does it look empty or full when viewing it from a Windows Explorer window of the desktop?

Comment: This was the bane of my existence for years.

Comment: If I remember right it reset the state after a reboot?

Answer (score 1):

It's a registry setting.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968873

Or use Microsoft's cool Fixit program.

http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9661135

Comment: HAVE ALL MY UPVOTES.  I LOVE YOU.